# Career choice：postdoc or non-tenure assistant professor job with little teaching load

Tags: postdocs, job-search, early-career, medicine

I am a PhD candidate and I am currently in the mist of choosing my career path.

A little about my current situation:
I have a family in a large city where my husband grew up in. We are not likely to move because of his family and job, so I have geographical restrictions. I enjoy research but hate the stress of publish or perish. I do not dislike teaching, but it’s not my passion.

The first position: a postdoc at a R1 medical school with a PI who does exactly what I am interested in (autism intervention). The PI has good reputation of supporting her postdocs and she is a rising star with lots of NIH grants. It’s a two year position, but the grant(NIH R01) has four more years. I think it’s possible the PI might extend my contract if I cannot secure a job within the first two years.

The second position: a non-tenure teaching position for a lower-ranked R1 medical school near us. The campus is a satalite campus of the larger R1 university. Lots of research resources are available for that campus as well. But it doesn’t seem like faculty there, at least similar positions, are publishing as much. The main focus is teaching. But they were trying really hard to impress me during the campus visit that they do support research. Promotion is not as stressful. 5 year assistant then associate. If in five years you do not get it, you can stay for longer to apply again. Teaching load is about 3 hours a week. I will be teaching a theme that run through the first two years of medical school. Although this campus is small, it is growing. Pro for this position is that I can work there and look for other positions that has more research focus, since teaching load is not as bad, I am hoping to continue my research. They do have an autism clinic and there are ways to connect with the local community to conduct my research.

I am torn between this two. My advisor would definitely tell me to go for the postdoc because of the NIH funding training is invaluable. But I have geographical limitations, I do not know if I can land a better position than the medical school teaching position after I complete my postdoc. I have been looking at social work tenure track positions( my background), even R1 universities ask their early career faculty to teach two courses per semester. That makes the teaching at medical school not bad at all to me. Also faculty positions do not come around easily especially given my specialty. The teaching position teaches the area I am researching by and large.

Any suggestions or your first hand experiences would be appreciated. Particularly from early career faculty in applied health’s science. I know I am so lucky. But the choice is hard. It’s a perfect dilemma. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE, and congrats on your offers! I suggest you try to "boil down" your post to the key question you would like us to advise you on. As it is, the question seems to be "which one should I pick," which will generate the unhelpful response "this depends on the specifics of your situation; only you can decide."

Comment: Thank you! I guess my main question is, is it possible to launch a research career with a teaching position. I am mostly interested in others’ experiences in these types of medical school teaching positions as clinical assistant professors.

Comment: In the first sentence, "mist" was probably a typo, but I think it's well worth **not** correcting.

Comment: *Teaching load is about 3 hours a week.* --- Is this a typo? If not, this is about as minimal teaching as exists, at least in my experience and area, and thus it would seem to me to be a no-brainer in choosing this, since they want you and there is a reasonably good chance that you can stay indefinitely and you're still located in the vicinity of several people who research what you're interested in (both where you would be at, as well as those who are at the other university, which I would assume is within a reasonable driving distance).

Comment: Possibly worth considering is what is the chance of another opening for you at this teaching school being available when you exhaust the time spent in the postdoc position? If it's extremely high, then maybe do the postdoc, then reevaluate things when it's over (maybe your husband will desire, or have to, take a job somewhere else by this time), knowing that you still have a good chance for getting a position at the teaching school.